# The register site is not inserting info into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to register accounts but can't, ever when try to do it doesn't insert anything into the table. So if I log out of the newly created account then try to sign in it wont work.

My data connection page is server.php. register page is register.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
       header("Location: index.php");
       exit();
   }
   ?>
<?php include('server.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="My Market">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
             <!-- Icons -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="last.jpg" type="image/jpg">  
        <!-- END Icons -->
    <title>My Market Market | Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my-login.css">
</head>
<body class="my-login-page">
    <section class="h-100">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center h-100">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <div class="brand">
                        <img src="last.jpg" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card fat">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center">My Market Registration</h4>
                            <form method="POST" action="" class="my-login-validation" novalidate="">
                              <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                                    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required autofocus value="<?php echo $username; ?>" >
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Input Username! 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">E-Mail Address</label>
                                    <input id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Your email is invalid
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_1" required data-eye>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Password is required
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="Confirm Password">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_2" required data-eye>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Password is required
                                    </div>
                                </div><br />
                        <center><img src="captcha.php" alt="Captcha"></center><br />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" placeholder="Captcha Code" required="required"  /><br />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="custom-checkbox custom-control">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" class="custom-control-input" required="">
                                        <label for="agree" class="custom-control-label">I agree to the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            You must agree with our Terms and Conditions
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
<body background="background2.webp">
                                <div class="form-group m-0">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="reg_user">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-4 text-center">
                                    Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                        Copyright &copy; 2019 &mdash; My Market
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/my-login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Server File

```
<?php
session_start();
function getBrowser()
{
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }
   
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Opera';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }
   
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
    }
   
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }
   
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}
   
    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
}
$ua=getBrowser();
$platform = $ua['platform'];
$useragent = $ua['userAgent'];
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$json = file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/php/$ip"); 
$data = json_decode($json); 
$country_code = $data->country_code;
$country_name = $data->country_name;

    $username = "";
    $email    = "";
    $errors = array(); 
    $_SESSION['success'] = "";

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST["captcha"];
    $captchaUser = filter_var($_POST["captcha"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
          if(empty($captcha)) {
              array_push($errors, "Please enter the captcha.");
      }else if($_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE'] == $captchaUser){
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

  $uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password_1);
  $lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $password_1);
  $number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $password_1);
  if(!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || strlen($password_1) < 8){ array_push($errors, "Password should be at least 8 characters in length and should include at least one upper case letter, and one number"); }
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { array_push($errors, "Please Enter Valid Email"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  
  if ($user) { 
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $date      = date("Y/m/d / h:i:sa");
    $password = md5($password_1);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users ('username', 'email', 'password', 'date', 'ip', 'code', 'country') 
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password', '$date', '$ip', '$country_code', '$country_name')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
  }

}else {
    array_push($errors, "Captcha is invalid.");
}
}

    // ... 

    // LOGIN USER
    if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST["captcha"];
    $captchaUser = filter_var($_POST["captcha"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
          if(empty($captcha)) {
              array_push($errors, "Please enter the captcha.");
      }else if($_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE'] == $captchaUser){
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Username is required");
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");
        }

        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $date      = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
                $query = "INSERT INTO sessions (username, ip, platform, useragent, date)
              VALUES('$username', '$ip', '$platform', '$useragent', '$date')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

                header('location: index.php');
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password");
            }
        }
          }else {
    array_push($errors, "Captcha is invalid.");
}
        
    }

?>
```

I need some help with it please! Can log in using old accounts in database but not register new accounts

Trying to change the MYSQL but it don't works!